# XAMLstackpanel creation in c# DragOver Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im working on creating `StackPanels` in C#. 
The xaml Im trying to replicate in C# is

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="BlanchedAlmond" DragOver="panel_DragOver" Drop="panel_Drop" AllowDrop="True" MinWidth="150">
```

Currently what I have is:

```
StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel
{
    MinWidth = 150,
    MinHeight = 150,
    AllowDrop = true
};
MainStack.Children.Add(myPanel);
```

Which currently works the only issue is that the `StackPanel` does not have the properties for `DragOver` and `Drop`, how can I add this to the C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not properties but events that you can hook up handlers to using the `+=` syntax:

```
StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel
{
    MinWidth = 150,
    MinHeight = 150,
    AllowDrop = true
};
myPanel.DragOver += panel_DragOver;
myPanel.Drop += panel_Drop;
MainStack.Children.Add(myPanel);
```

Of course the handlers, `panel_DragOver` and `panel_Drop`, must still be defined just like before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does have it.

```
var sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Drop += (o, arg) => { };
```

You just cannot assign an event within the body of object creation.